# How can I filter one column based on multiple groups in another column in R?

Tags: r, filter, tidyverse

I have values in column A which belong to 2 groups, A and B. I want to filter just for values in ID which have multiple groupings in Group. E.g. here, value 1 would qualify as what I want to select.

Any ideas on how I'd go about doing this?

| ID | Group |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | B |
| 3 | B |
| 3 | B |

I tried using dplyr:

```
df %>%
filter(Group == "A" & Group == "B")
```

But this returns no output, as no value has both A and B in the same row.

Answer (score 2):

We can group by 'ID' and select only those having 'Group's with more than one distinct element (`n_distinct`)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(n_distinct(Group) > 1) %>%
    ungroup
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Group = c("A", 
"B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```